# Can someone please provide the meaning of the Hari Sankara Stotram by Adi Sankara from MAdhaviya Sankara Digvijayam?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, translation-request, stotra

I'm looking for Hari Sankara Stotram By Adi Sankara and a breakdown of the words in the stotram, along with the meaning of the verses.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.